# Put journal at the same line as the title in bibentry

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing, bibentry

I have this bibliography entry in a `bib` file:

```
@article{de2019near,
  title={\mbox{Near-convex} archetypal analysis},
  author={De Handschutter, Pierre and Gillis, Nicolas and Vandaele, Arnaud and Siebert, Xavier},
  journal={IEEE Signal Processing Letters},
  volume={27},
  pages={81--85},
  year={2019},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

In my document, I am writing this command `\footnotesize{\textit{\bibentry{de2019near}}}` but the journal appears on a new line while there is still space remaining at the right of the title. Is it possible to put all on the same line ?

Side question: why does the title appear in blue ? Is it possible to change it also ?[image]

Note that I am using `plainnat` bibliographystyle

Comment: Please provide a small, complete sample document that illustrates the behavior that you want to change. Without knowing all the settings (class, packages etc) it is hard to say anything meaningful about your problem. Actually, you have been asked for an MWE for at least two of you earlier questions, so this shouldn't come as a surprise

Comment: Off-topic: `\footnotesize` is a switch, i.e., it doesn't take an argument. Thus, `\footnotesize{\textit{\bibentry{de2019near}}}` probably is a mistake; do change it to `{\footnotesize \textit{\bibentry{de2019near}}}`.

Comment: Regarding your question "why does the title appear in blue?" The only possibly answer has got to be, "because you've loaded some code that colors the title field. Unfortunately, as you have (once again) not posted the relevant code, the answer can't be more specific at this point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily redefine `\newblock`. This will disable most of beamer's enhancements for the bibliography, including the added line breaks as well as the additions of colours.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{de2019near, 
  title={\mbox{Near-convex} archetypal analysis}, 
  author={De Handschutter, Pierre and Gillis, Nicolas and Vandaele, Arnaud and Siebert, Xavier}, 
  journal={IEEE Signal Processing Letters}, 
  volume={27}, 
  pages={81--85}, 
  year={2019}, 
  publisher={IEEE} 
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  test

  \nobibliography{\jobname}  
  \def\newblock{}
  
  {\footnotesize \textit{\bibentry{de2019near}}}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]